# Como traer con la clausula in los valores nulos de un registro?

Tags: sql, oracle-18c

Hola espero y se encuentren bien, tengo un problema lo que es que quiero trarme los registro de una columnas que vengan nulos y a su vez los demas que encuentre,algo como los siguiente:

```
SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION, NOM_SISTEMA, serie
    from complemento_pago WHERE TIPO_DOCUMENTO =4 AND ID_ESTATUS =6 AND UUID IS NULL 
        and TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') =  TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)
        and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335))                                    
        And serie  in ('PA', 'PB', 'PC','PD', 'PE','PF','PG','PH', null);
```

Por obvias la consulta de arriba está mal, como puedo traerme los registros nulos, algo parecido a como se usa `ISNULL` en lo siguiente:

```
SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION, NOM_SISTEMA, serie
    from complemento_pago WHERE TIPO_DOCUMENTO =4 AND ID_ESTATUS =6 AND UUID IS NULL 
        and TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') =  TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)
        and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335))                                           
        And serie is null;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan ayudar, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios, saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia la condición final por lo siguiente:

```
--  |  Estos paréntesis son muy importantes                                 |
--  V                                                                       V
And (serie  in ('PA', 'PB', 'PC','PD', 'PE','PF','PG','PH') or serie IS NULL);
```

Con este cambio el código completo quedaría

```
SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION, NOM_SISTEMA, serie
    from complemento_pago WHERE TIPO_DOCUMENTO =4 AND ID_ESTATUS =6 AND UUID IS NULL 
        and TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') =  TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/RRRR')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)
        and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335))                                    
        And (serie  in ('PA', 'PB', 'PC','PD', 'PE','PF','PG','PH') or serie IS NULL);
```

#### Importancia de los paréntesis (Actualización)

*En atención a tu comentario relacionado con el uso de los paréntesis, agrego la siguiente explicación.*

En el contexto de las expresiones lógicas, los paréntesis son utilizados para agrupar condiciones cuando combinamos operadores.

En relación con los operadores lógicos, debemos tener claro lo siguiente:

- **AND**: Cuando se tienen condiciones compuestas conectadas con el operador `AND`, cada una debe ser verdadera para que la expresión general sea verdad.

  `1 = 1 AND 2 = 2`  el resultado es verdad porque cada condición es verdadera.
  `1 = 1 AND 2 = 3`  el resultado es falso porque una condición es falsa.
- **OR**: Cuando se tienen condiciones compuestas conectadas con el operador `OR`, basta con que una sea verdadera para que la expresión general sea verdad.
  `1 = 1 OR 2 = 3` el resultado es verdad porque una condición es verdadera.

En el caso de tu pregunta, tienes en la clausula `WHERE` 6 condiciones conectadas con el operador `AND`.

Para simplificar el ejemplo, voy a representar cada condición con una letra, comenzando con
`A` para la condición `TIPO_DOCUMENTO =4` y terminando en la letra
`F` para la condición `serie  in ('PA', 'PB', 'PC','PD', 'PE','PF','PG','PH');`
*aún no incluye el requerimiento del null*.

Entonces la clausula `WHERE` se vería de la siguiente manera:

```
WHERE A and B and C and D and E and F;
```

Debido al operador `AND`, todas las condiciones (de la `A` a la `F`) deben ser verdad para que el registro sea incluido.

Pero surge un nuevo requerimiento, ahora debemos incluir cualquier registro que cumpla las condiciones de la `A` a la `E` y en el caso de la `F` debe incluir los valores de la lista
`('PA', 'PB', 'PC','PD', 'PE','PF','PG','PH')` **o** (or) los que sean nulos.

Digamos, entonces, que tenemos una nueva condición con la letra `G` para el caso
`serie IS NULL`

Si omitimos los paréntesis y creamos la clusula `WHERE` de la siguiente manera

```
WHERE A and B and C and D and E and F OR G
```

El resultado sería:

- Cualquier registro que cumpla las condiciones de la `A` a la `F` y además
- Cualquier registro que cumpla la `G` sin importar que alguna condicion de la `A` a la `F` no se cumpla.

Entonces como el nuevo requerimiento está relacionado unicamente a la condición `F`, necesitamos agruparlo con parentesis para que sea evaluado como una unidad

```
WHERE A and B and C and D and E and (F OR G)
```

La expresion `(F OR G)` será verdadera cuando el valor de `serie` está en la lista o sea nulo, con cualquier otro valor la condición agrupada `(F OR G)` sería falso y por lo tanto el registro no sería incluido.

Comment: Hola Pablo Gonzalez muchas gracias lo probaré, una cosa podrías por favor explicarme eso de los parentesis por que van por favor? Saludos

Comment: Buen día @cratus666jose, edité mi respuesta con la explicación de los paréntesis, espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: Hola @Pablo Gutiérrez, muchisimas gracias por tu explicación, me servirá bastante para mis proximos proyecto, te mando un cordial saludo y que andes bien! :)

Comment: @cratus666jose, es bueno saber que la explicación relacionada con el uso de los paréntesis aporta un valor adicional. Por favor déjame saber si mi respuesta (a la pregunta principal) produjo el resultado que esperabas.

Comment: Hola @Pablo Gutiérrez buenas noches, quedó perfecto y explicación mas claro que el agua amigo, te agradezco mucho, te mando las buenas vibras saludos